# How do I use a NodeJS package with RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I would like to use the the `node-bencoding` package with my current RequireJS project setup, but I have been unable to get it configured.

I have followed [these instructions](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html) and have ran:

> npm install requirejs
>
> npm install node-bencoding

Then in my `app.js` file I had changed it:

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');

// Place third party dependencies in the lib folder
//
// Configure loading modules from the lib directory,
// except 'app' ones,
requirejs.config({
    nodeRequire: require,
    "baseUrl": "assets/js/lib",
    "paths": {
        "app": "../app",
        "jquery": "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min",
        "angularjs": "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min"
    },
});
```

However when I load the page I get the error:

> Error: Module name "requirejs" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([]) http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded

I'm not exactly sure where I should have my `node_modules` directory. My directory structure is as follows: all my JS files are contained within src/assets/js - there is assets/js/app and assets/js/lib as is the RequireJS convention. Currently I have put my node_modules directory in src/.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to use it in a browser. And your application is not server side JavaScript, so RequireJS usage sample in a Node does not apply. In this case you would like to use node only to optimize your scripts.

I recently blogged about [**Understanding AMD & RequireJS**](http://www.devbridge.com/articles/understanding-amd-requirejs), it might be useful.